# How to ration amount in purely functional style

Tags: javascript, lodash, purely-functional

I need to distribute certain amounts to array of people according to their score. The rule is that their demands are met according to their position with whatever remains. 
In JavaScript using Lo-Dash ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hademuya/1/edit)):

```
var amount = 1000,
  people = [
    { name : 'Joe', score: 40, demand: 400},
    { name : 'Sue', score: 30, demand: 350},
    { name : 'Kim', score: 25, demand: 300},
    { name : 'Ron', score: 20, demand: 250}
  ];

function  distribute(people, amount){
   return _.map(_.sortBy(people,'need'),function(person){      
     var ration = Math.min(person.demand,amount); 
     amount -= ration; // This is the state (mutation) that I want to avoid
     return _.assign(person,{ ration: ration})
 });
}
console.log(distribute(people, amount));
```

Result:

```
[{  demand: 400,  name: "Joe",  ration: 400,  score: 40}, 
 {  demand: 350,  name: "Sue",  ration: 350,  score: 30}, 
 {  demand: 300,  name: "Kim",  ration: 250,  score: 25}, 
 {  demand: 250,  name: "Ron",  ration:   0,  score: 20}]
```

Since the solution depends on the order,  is it possible to change this code to make it purely functional?

Comment: That solution seems to be okay. What is your question about?

Comment: It uses mutation,since I depend on mutating amount. I would prefer functional solution if possible.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review. It should belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: _"This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)."_ By what reading of the help center article do you think this question is not about programming?

Comment: I believe that the problem is general enough of using  intermediate state and should be covered by "a specific programming problem" of turning iterative into purely functional solution. The code supplied was for illustration of the mutation based solution and to provide comparison results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functional solution is a *fold*:

```
function distribute(people, amount) {
  return _.foldl(_.sortBy(people, 'score'), function(result, person) {
    var ration = Math.min(person.demand, result.remaining);
    var resultPerson = _.assign(person, { ration: ration });
    return { people: result.people.concat(resultPerson),
             remaining: result.remaining - ration };
  }, { people: [], remaining: amount }).people;
}
```

Comment: I just wrote that and was hoping for something better :) http://jsbin.com/qicujaco/1/edit since its ugly

Comment: Nice :). Yeah, a plain `for` loop would be most readable here I think.

Comment: answering a solution that is out of scope is a *pollution*, nothing else.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by that. I think this is the exact answer for the question. How is it out of scope? What scope?